# Transferir HTML via arquivos em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

To fazendo um sistema de pedidos, onde o usuário clica no link para cair em uma página que vai selecionar os itens que vão pro pedido.

Eu preciso de alguma forma de identificar o que o usuário selecionou nesses checkbox e passar para a página que faz o pedido... tem como salvar html em tipo um sessionStorage, ou algo do tipo e depois recuperar na outra página?

Agradeço desde já

Comment: Na verdade o correto seria utilizar um `<form>` e neste form ter campos a serem enviados para a página que está como `action` do form. E nesta página você consegue resgatar os campos enviados através de get ou post

Comment: mas se tu quiseres também existe o localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage

Comment: Já me deu uma ideia do que fazer, valeu